# Django - many types of User - add/change instances including User fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When I started the modelling of my application, as I have many types of users, I first though about entirely defining my own User model, or subclassing it. However I eventually chose to follow the standard recommended way, using a OneToOneField :

```
class Member(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    ... more fields ..

class Particular(Member):
    ... even more fields ...

class Professional(Member):
    ... even more fields ...

class Brand(Member):
    ... even more fields ...

class Staff(Member):
    ... even more fields ...
```

However, now I'm facing issues dealing with the admin. I have my 4 XxxAdmin, but I can't edit username, first_name, last_name and email fields, since they are in the User model which have no foreign key to my custom member types. I can't either add members since it requires to create a User first and I disabled the foreign key select field since we have more than 100.000 users, it is a bit time consuming. And this is anyway not user-friendly (the admin is not intended for devs).

So I'm scratching my head for days in order to find the better way to have :

- A friendly add/change form for Particular where I can edit some User fields
- A friendly add/change form for Professional where I can edit some User fields
- A friendly add/change form for Brand where I can edit some User fields
- A friendly add/change form for Staff where I can edit some User fields
- Keep the original change form for User, for advanced edition

Is it possible to get it done with ParticularAdmin, ProfessionalAdmin, BrandAdmin and StaffAdmin, or should I define custom views in UserAdmin?

Details: Django 1.8, without extension/plugin currently installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, here is the best solution I found:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(auth.admin.UserAdmin):

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(UserAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^particular/add/$', self.add_part_view),
            url(r'^professional/add/$', self.add_pro_view),
            url(r'^brand/add/$', self.add_brand_view),
            url(r'^staff/add/$', self.add_staff_view),
            url(r'^particular/([0-9]+)/$', self.change_part_view),
            url(r'^professional/([0-9]+)/$', self.change_pro_view),
            url(r'^brand/([0-9]+)/$', self.change_brand_view),
            url(r'^staff/([0-9]+)/$', self.change_staff_view),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def add_part_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        self.inlines = [ParticularInline]
        return self.add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

    def change_part_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        self.inlines = [ParticularInline]
        return self.change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def add_pro_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        self.inlines = [ProfessionalInline]
        return self.add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

    def change_pro_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        self.inlines = [ProfessionalInline]
        return self.change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def add_brand_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        self.inlines = [BrandInline]
        return self.add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

    def change_brand_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        self.inlines = [BrandInline]
        return self.change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def add_staff_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        self.inlines = [StaffInline]
        return self.add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

    def change_staff_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        self.inlines = [StaffInline]
        return self.change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

And and redirect `add_view()` and `change_view()` of `ParticularAdmin`, `ProfessionalAdmin`, `BrandAdmin` and `StaffAdmin`.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem a couple of times with Django. I am still not sure if a perfect solution exists. However I suggest using `pre_save` signals to create the django user for each member type.

```
class Particular(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True,related_name='particular')
    first_name=models.CharField(.....)
    last_name=models.CharField(.....)
    username=models.CharField(.....)
    email=models.EmailField(.....)
    password=models.CharField(....)


from django.db.models.signals import pre_save,post_save
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

def particular_pre_save(sender,**kwargs):
   instance=kwargs['instance']
   if instance.pk is None:#new instance
       U=User()
   else:
       U=instance.user


   U.first_name=instance.first_name
   U.last_name=instance.last_name
   U.username=instance.username
   U.password=make_password(instance.password)#hash password

   U=U.save()
   # do something with user U, perhaps add permissions or groups
   instance.user=U
   instance.password=make_password(instance.password)#hash password

pre_save.connect(particular_pre_save,Particular)
#####in forms.py
class ParticularForm(forms.Form):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
         model = Particular
         exclude = ['user']
```

Every time someone creates/changes a Particular instance a User is also created/changed. You have to then use ParticularForm in your Django Admin class. This approach creates some redundancy since both the User table and the Particular table contain the same data.

You may also add a similar pre_save for the User model so as to update the Particular Model when the User model changes. Code not tested.

```
def user_post_save(sender,**kwargs):
   instance=kwargs['instance']
   query=instance.particular.all()
   if query:
      P=query[0]
      P.first_name=instance.first_name
      P.last_name=instance.last_name
      P.username=instance.username
      P.password=make_password(instance.password)#hash password

      P.save()

post_save.connect(user_post_save,User)
```

Comment: Duplicate User fields in the Member model is not really appealing nor DRY. :/